# How to tell the version of jetty that apt-get will install?

Tags: package-management

Is it possible to see what version of jetty will be installed on the various versions of Ubuntu?

Is it online somewhere?

Also, is it possible to see the package so I can tweak it if required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, here is the way that I usually use. Depending on the version of ubuntu you're currently running, you might need to install aptitude. You can do that by opening a terminal and typing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Once aptitude is installed then you would type the following to determine the version that would be installed or is installed depending.

```
sudo aptitude show jetty
```

Hope this helps!

Chris

Comment: aptitude was [removed](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/maverick-changes/2010-June/001202.html) from standard in 2010.

Answer (score 7):

To see what version(s) of Jetty are available for installation on your system:

```
apt-cache policy jetty
```

This lists the installed version (if any) and all the versions available for installation, and indicates which one would be installed by default.

In more recent Ubuntu releases, the package name contains the major version number, which potentially allows installing multiple major versions at the same time (although no Ubuntu release offers this at the time I'm writing). You can find the package name(s) in a terminal by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after typing `apt-cache policy jetty`, or by searching:

```
apt-cache search jetty
```

If you want to know about other Ubuntu releases, look [on packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jetty).

If you want to see the package before installation, download it but don't install it yet:

```
apt-get -d install jetty
```

The package is in `/var/lib/apt/cache/jetty*.deb`.

Comment: if I use `apt-cache policy jetty` I get an error message of "Unable to locate package jetty" however if I make a guess as to the current version and use `apt-cache policy jetty9` I get a message telling me none are installed however 9.4.45-1 is the Candidate. I also tried `apt-cache policy jetty10` and received the error message "Unable to locate package jetty10".

Answer (score 3):

[packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) can be searched to see which version are included with each release.  Some packages from future releases are fairly easy to install on an older Ubuntu release.  Jetty is likely one of them.

You can download the source packages from the above site.  However, I would recommend against tweaking the package.  It is relatively easy to do, but you won't get important security patches.

A note about package versions.  These are the original versions.  Security patches are backported to this release, and the available package is updated.  These patches are applied when you update the package.  If you use one of the automatic update packages, they may be applied automatically depending on your settings.

Debian/Ubuntu makes it quite easy to adapt the configuration to your needs.  For packages that support `conf.d` configuration, I would recommend using it rather than modifying the original configuration.  This will make version updates much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing aptitude, it is faster to use `apt-cache` :

> apt-cache showpkg jetty

This command will show full informations about the packet, even if it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use aptitude, you can use apt instead :

```
apt search jetty | grep jetty
```

the result is

```
libjetty8-extra-java/xenial,xenial,now 8.1.19-1 all  [installé, automatique]
libjetty8-java/xenial,xenial,now 8.1.19-1 all  [installé, automatique]
libjetty8-java-doc/xenial,xenial 8.1.19-1 all
libjetty9-extra-java/xenial,xenial 9.2.14-1 all
libjetty9-java/xenial,xenial 9.2.14-1 all
```

consequently you have the choice betweel jetty8 and jetty9